# Can't deploy blazor MAUI desktop application as .exe

Tags: blazor, preview, .net-6.0, maui

I downloaded latest 17.1 preview and created blazor-maui app from template. Wanted to create single exe from the build. So clicked publish and selected target win-x64. I get this error when i try to publish

```html
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: BlazorMauiApp2, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>BlazorMauiApp2 -> C:\Dashboard\Workspace\microsoft\windowsforms\BlazorMauiApp2\bin\Release\net6.0-windows10.0.19041\win-x64\BlazorMauiApp2.dll
2>------ Publish started: Project: BlazorMauiApp2, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>Determining projects to restore...
2>The RuntimeIdentifier 'win-x64' is invalid.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Hello, any progress with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Actually i follow this steps and it works:

1- Download latest Visual Studio Preview version (17.4.0 version 2.1)

2- Create new blazor maui project

3- Publish project

4- Select [Sideloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/sideload-apps-in-windows-10)

5- Create or use your [Current Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/msix/package/create-certificate-package-signing)

6- Create a new publish profile (in your case win-x64)

7- Select a location for the installer
8- Enjoy

Hope it helps!

If it doesn't work, share to me your publish profile so i can check it

Comment: Does this create a .exe file or an installer?